# ¿Cómo sumo los valores de un diccionario que no son cadenas?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy intentando sumar los valores de un diccionario siempre que se cumpla la condicion de que sea un numero y no un str.

He usado el método `isinstance()` tras iterar en el diccionario pero simplemente no he sabido continuar una vez localizados los str.

```
magic_dict = dict(val1=44, val2='secret value', val3=55.0, val4=1)

for key in magic_dict:
  print(key, ":", magic_dict[key]) 
  result = isinstance(magic_dict[key], str)
  if result:
    print('Es str')
  else:
    print('No es str')
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo usando `sum()` y un iterador:

```
sum(i if not isinstance(i, str) else 0 for i in dicc.values())
```

O mejor aún (gracias a [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia)) poniendo un filtro en el iterador:

```
sum(i for i in dicc.values() if not isinstance(i, str))
```

Como comenta [ChemaCortes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/630/chemacortes), también puedes validar que es un número (así en general, sea entero o decimal) con la librería [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html):

```
import numbers

sum(i for i in dicc.values() if isinstance(i, numbers.Number))
```

---

En el código que muestras, necesitas llevar un contador:

```
suma = 0
for key in magic_dict:
  print(key, ":", magic_dict[key]) 
  result = isinstance(magic_dict[key], str)
  if result:
    print('Es str')
  else:
    print('No es str')
    suma += magic_dict[key]
```

De todas formas, fíjate que estás usando `for key in magic_dict` para iterar sobre los índices, cuando podrías hacerlo directamente sobre los valores. O sobre ambos con `for key, value in magic_dict.items()`. Recomiendo usar las alternativas expuestas más arriba.

Comment: O también usando un filtro en vez de una expresión condicional: `sum(i for i in magic_dict.values() if not isinstance(i,str))` La sintaxis se parece, pero no es lo mismo porque en este caso la suma que "ve" `sum()` tiene menos elementos, sólo aquellos en los que `i` no era cadena

Comment: @abulafia oh, mucho mejor. Actualizo mi publicación usándola, muchas gracias

Comment: Solo por dejarlo perfecto, es mejor comprobar si es un número validando contra `numbers.Number`: `sum(i for i in d.values() if isinstance(i, numbers.Number))`

Comment: @ChemaCortes entre todos me lo estáis dejando niquelado :) Muchas gracias, edité añadiendo esta versión